# http-server net serving the fresh js file

Tags: javascript, httpserver

I haven't used http-server npm module before!

i was just getting starting with using service worker by creating an example app using [this blog as a source](https://medium.com/izettle-engineering/beginners-guide-to-web-push-notifications-using-service-workers-cb3474a17679)

In this the author have used http-server to demonstrate service worker!

From the blog, I copied the code snippet to check if chrome is supported

```
const check = () => {
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
      throw new Error('No Service Worker support!')
    }
    if (!('PushManager' in window)) {
      throw new Error('No Push API Support!')
    }
    console.log('Everything works fine')
  }
  const main = () => {
    check()
  }
  main()
```

Notice the `console.log('Everything works fine')`

Now, as i proceeded with Article, I changed my main.js as instructed to this

```
const check = () => {
    if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
      throw new Error('No Service Worker support!')
    }
    if (!('PushManager' in window)) {
      throw new Error('No Push API Support!')
    }
    console.log(`Browser supports Pushmanager and Service worker`)
  }

  // Async so we can use await 
  const  main = async () => {
    check()
    const swRegistration = await registerServiceWorker();
  }


  //To run service worker we need to first register service worker 
  //Registering Service Worker
  const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
    const swRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('service.js'); //notice the file name
    return swRegistration;
}
```

but when I go the page, it keeps logging this from our first code snippet in the console

```
Everything works fine
```

I checked the main.js, and it appears the server is still serving the previous main.js instead of new one.

If I go manually to my file and open it without the server, the main.js shows my new code changes.

I have tried turning of the server (using ctrl/cmd + c) and restarting it again but no help.

Can someone help me out in fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `http-server` tells the browser to [cache pages for an hour by default](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#available-options):

> `-c` Set cache time (in seconds) for cache-control max-age header, e.g. -c10 for 10 seconds (defaults to '3600'). To disable caching, use -c-1.

Restart the server with `http-server -c-1`, then do a hard refresh in the browser (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+R</kbd> in Firefox or Chrome).

Comment: you can just disable your cache on the network tab in chrome